# file_field().set crashing watir

Tags: watir

When using file_field().set, my watir script crahes with a huge stack trace. I'm running on Windows 7 64, using Watir through cucumber.  I am using IE10 as my browser.

Here is the beginning of it:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.13.0/lib/rautomation/adapter/win_32/functions.rb:294:
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]
```

And here is the end:

```
c:/Code/trunk/source/cucumber/webapp/lib/cucumber/lcpic/features/step_definition/newbusiness.rb:465:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-4.0.1/lib/watir-classic/element_extensions.rb:19:in `method_missing'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-4.0.1/lib/watir-classic/dialogs/file_field.rb:34:in `set'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-4.0.1/lib/watir-classic/dialogs/file_field.rb:48:in `set_file_name'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.13.0/lib/rautomation/window.rb:214:in `text_field'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.13.0/lib/rautomation/window.rb:224:in `wait_until_present'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.13.0/lib/rautomation/wait_helper.rb:15:in `wait_until'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.13.0/lib/rautomation/window.rb:224:in `block in wait_until_present'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.13.0/lib/rautomation/window.rb:155:in `present?'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.13.0/lib/rautomation/window.rb:138:in `exists?'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.13.0/lib/rautomation/adapter/win_32/window.rb:90:in `exists?'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.13.0/lib/rautomation/adapter/win_32/window.rb:48:in `hwnd'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.13.0/lib/rautomation/adapter/win_3127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2014 10:11:33] "GET /status?_=1405692621800 HTTP/1.1" 200 15 0.0020
2/functions.rb:140:in `window_hwnd'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.13.0/lib/rautomation/adapter/win_32/functions.rb:294:in `find_hwnd'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.13.0/lib/rautomation/adapter/win_32/functions.rb:294:in `enum_windows'
```

Comment: Can you post (the mimimal amount of) sample HTML and watir code to replicate the error?

Comment: Here is the call that produces the error:
browser.file_field(id: 'file_APP').when_present.set(@image)   

where @image = File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/bb.jpg'


Here is the html for that page:

Comment: Here is the html for that page:
<input name="file_APP" id="file_APP" style="" type="file"/>

Comment: This issue is also posted on the [Watir General mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/watir-general/SxyZSlNROVQ).